qgis georeferenced map seems to be stuck on a point of reference
I am creating maps in QGIS and when I export them and open in them in Avenza they all say that the map location is 120 km away even though the maps are in different locations. It's as if something in qgis is creating a the same georeferenced point on all my maps. How do I fix this?
reset project projection
ensured all layers were in proper CRS

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
